# Send image from Python to C++ through Boost

Tags: python, c++, boost, tesseract, python-tesseract

I'm trying to optimize my program on Python with Boost and replace some Python code with C++ functions.

**Python code:**

```
 from PIL import Image
 for i in xrange(len(lines)):
   im = Image.fromarray(lines[i])
   line = pytesseract.image_to_string(im, "ukr+ukrb") # working to slow
```

**And code on C++:**

```
Pix *image = pixRead("/home/lucas63/Downloads/test.tif"); # here i need to get image directly from Python
 api->SetImage(image);
 outText = api->GetUTF8Text();
 printf("OCR output:\n%s", outText);`
```

So, i need to make two things :

1. Send image from Python to C++ using `Boost.Python`.
2. Send array of images to C++ (I want to increase performance by using multithreating in C++).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using [tesserocr](https://github.com/sirfz/tesserocr) which wraps around tesseract's C++ API:

```
import tesserocr

with tesserocr.PyTessBaseAPI(lang='ukr+ukrb') as api:
    for l in lines:
        im = Image.fromarray(l)
        api.SetImage(im)
        line = api.GetUTF8Text()
```

This will initialize the API once and use it to process multiple images.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i will try to replace py-tesseract with tesserocr, and i will write later about results